# Connect azure web site to on-premise database over site-to-site vpn

Tags: database, azure, web, local

my goal is to run an azure web site that accesses data from our local company database.

I followed a tutorial on the web to setup an azure virtual network and connect it via site-to-site vpn to our local company network. In the azure portal I can see that the connection is actually working and that data is received and transmitted.

What do I have to do make the azure web site connect to the database? Is it enough to enter a connection string in the web config? 
Is it meant to work this way, or is the site-to-site vpn only set up to access azure virtual machines from the company network.

Let me know if I should provide more details on the connection overall.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Best regards,
Frank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Web Sites do not support the Azure Virtual Network (as of 8/22/2013);
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/choose-web-app-service/

You will need to create a cloud service deployment instead if you would like to use Virtual Network and access the on-premises database.  Once that is done and your firewall is properly configured, it is like you say just a connection string.

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the info. So for a first test I think the easiest would be to create a web server vm and start from there.

Comment: Mixing Azure Web Sites, Cloud Services and VMs (Iaas) gets tricky real quick.  For example, say you have a web site or a cloud service and you want a dedicated SQL Server box...ok you start a SQL Server VM, but the problem is you don't want to go over the internet, so the solution is to use Virtual network.  Next the client web site can't communicate with with SQL Server, so now you need a private DNS server.  As you can in even simple scenarios mixing the Azure cloud stack gets expensive/complex real quick.  I really hope they address this in the next coming year.

Comment: This is no longer the case, please see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/azure-sql-databases-api-management-media-services-websites-role-based-access-control-and-more

Answer (score 0):

I am currently looking into connecting Azure Web Sites to an on-prem SQL database using the Azure Service Bus:

- http://www.bradygaster.com/post/windowsazurewebsites-onprem-servicebus
- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay/