# Azure website to connect with databases on-premises as well as on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I want to publish my website on to azure, but the database should be on-premises for each client. One default database, however, should be on Azure too. In my asp.net MVC website, after my connection with default database is established, then I change the connection string based on the credentials entered by the user on login screen. This user database would be present at the client.

Do I simply change the connection string in web.config or do I need to set it up as follows?

I read this article that looks familiar to my scenario 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections
Should I follow this article directly or do I need to create "cloud service deployment" as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379442/connect-azure-web-site-to-on-premise-database-over-site-to-site-vpn) article?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18379442/7920473) you referred for cloud service deployment is very old.

Go ahead with Hybrid connections. [Read best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-network-security).

Comment: What do you mean, "go ahead with hybrid connections"? Why??? How is this definitive?

Comment: @DavidMakogon OP was asking for this or that. If you have better choice, let us know we all will learn.

Comment: @downvoters, feel free to edit my answer text the way you want or propose a new answer for OP.

Comment: Nobody needs to edit what you wrote. The issue is that there is no way to properly answer the OP's question. And hybrid connections require proper setup at every client's site, which has its own specific requirements (and should involve each client's IT staff). This is not a simple decision to make.